# React-native geolocation (android) error

Tags: android, react-native

Iam trying to use geolocation on my react-native app.
I've started by following the React Native Geolocation Tutorial but am not having any luck.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import {styles} from './locationPageStyles.js'

export default class LocationPage extends Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      initialPosition: 'unknownn',
      lastPosition: 'unknown'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
     (position) => {
       var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
       this.setState({initialPosition});
     },
     (error) => alert(error),
     {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      var lastPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
      this.setState({lastPosition});
    });
  }

 componentWillUnmount() {
   navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
 }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigator.push({component: "startPage"})} >
          <View style={{paddingVertical: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
            <Text>Go to page ONE</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View>
         <Text>There is your geo {this.state.initialPosition} and {this.state.lastPosition}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

    )
  }
}
```

After some time - alert with "Location timeout ended" message.  I was trying to increase timeOut, but without results. (

GPS, locations, Wifi on device enabled. Permissios added. Google maps work fine. Where is a problem? pls, help!

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, it was caused by enableHighAccuracy: true. Don't know why, but with it it didn't work at all.

Comment: I solved this. I am just went outside and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> use this code it may helps you

```
 - Don't forget to give location permission in manifest file
```

- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        latitude: null,
        longitude: null,
        error: null,
      };
}

componentDidMount(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position)=>{
        //const ipos = JSON.stringify(Position);
        this.setState({
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            error: null,
          });
    },
    (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
  );
}
```